# Multi Array From Query

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I am doing a count and sum on each item, and need the array to look like this.

```
[Date] => 
         [device_type1] => [all the data]
         [device_type2] => [all the data]
```

Thing is I am doing a search through each and then all of them return a date, I need all of them to be under that one date, and inside that array to hold each of the devices as key and inside that all the information. here is what I have so far.

```
$all_device_types = array('pole','covert','firewatch','internet','trailer','slave','project');
foreach ($all_device_types as $adt) {
    $du->select("CONCAT(YEAR(uptime_date),'-',MONTH(uptime_date),'-',DAY(uptime_date)) as year_month_day,

                             SUM(uptime_router) as router,

                             COUNT(uptime_router) as router_count,

                             uptime_device_type as device_type,

                            date(uptime_date) as data_date","

                            WHERE uptime_device_type = '".$adt."'

                            GROUP BY CONCAT(YEAR(uptime_date),'-',MONTH(uptime_date),'-',DAY(uptime_date))

                            ORDER BY uptime_date ASC");


                            $all_results = array();
                            while( $all_row = $du->fetch() ){

                                if ($adt == $all_device_types[0]) {
                                    $dates[] = $all_row['data_date'];
                                    $adt_0 = $all_row;
                                } elseif ($adt == $all_device_types[1]) {
                                    $adt_1[] = $all_row;
                                } elseif ($adt == $all_device_types[2]) {
                                    $adt_2[] = $all_row;
                                } elseif ($adt == $all_device_types[3]) {
                                    $adt_3[] = $all_row;
                                } elseif ($adt == $all_device_types[4]) {
                                    $adt_4[] = $all_row;
                                } elseif ($adt == $all_device_types[5]) {
                                    $adt_5[] = $all_row;
                                } elseif ($adt == $all_device_types[6]) {
                                    $adt_6[] = $all_row;
                                }

                            }

                        }
```

One of the results looks like this.

```
 [pole] => Array
        (
            [year_month_day] => 2017-9-5
            [router] => 4408
            [router_count] => 4620
            [device_type] => pole
            [data_date] => 2017-09-05
        )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like it could be simplified quite a bit. Instead of looping over the device types and running a separate query for each one, you can just add the device type to your GROUP BY and get all your results in a single query.

I think `CONCAT(YEAR(uptime_date),'-',MONTH(uptime_date),'-',DAY(uptime_date))` should output the same thing as `date(uptime_date)`, and you should be able to use the aliases in your GROUP BY and ORDER BY clauses.

```
$du->select("DATE(uptime_date) as data_date,
             uptime_device_type as device_type,
             SUM(uptime_router) as router,
             COUNT(uptime_router) as router_count,
             GROUP BY data_date, device_type
             ORDER BY data_date, device_type");
```

If I'm mistaken and you do need the CONCAT version, add it back in of course, but the main thing is adding device_type to the GROUP BY and eliminating the WHERE clause.

Then as you fetch your results, you can insert them directly into the multidimensional structure you want.

```
while( $row = $du->fetch() ) {
    $all_results[$row['data_date']][$row['device_type']][] = $row;

    // to calculate totals for all the devices for each date
    if (!isset($all_results[$row['data_date']]['all_devices']) {
        // initialize if not set
        $all_results[$row['data_date']]['all_devices'] = [
            'router' => 0, 'router_count' => 0];
    }
    // increment values
    $all_results[$row['data_date']]['all_devices']['router'] += $row['router'];
    $all_results[$row['data_date']]['all_devices']['router_count'] += $row['router_count'];
}
```

Comment: Great! Thank you so much! Also what if I wanted to add another field All_devices ... every date would calculate the devices router and router count and have a total sum? Would this be included in the while loop or after it all?

Comment: You're welcome. You should be able to do that in the while loop as well. I can update the answer to show you.